# Importing a model into Unity with Textures (Textures do not load)

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d-model

I am trying to import a model into unity and the model imports but without any textures.

I tried putting a texture folder next to it but it doesn't work, I tried various ways of putting the textures but they still don't work.

Here is the exact model I want to import -> https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/fuse-civilian-1-6fc4bddf4d364e6b9fa2f050011e03ce

Comment: What is the file format of your model? some ones do not support textures, and in anothers you need to import them separately

Comment: @Chico3001 I have gave a link to the exact model I want to import, but it is .fbx and all the textures are in a separate folder.

Answer (score 0):

The steps are easy:

1. Import your model into the Project folder
2. Select your FBX file and in the Inspector click the Materials button
3. If the FBX has embeded Textures and Materials the Extract buttons will be enabled
4. If enabled click the extract Textures button a select a destination folder
5. If enabled repeat with Materials
6. Drag the FBX into the Hierarchy window to inspect it, if it was well packed then its done
7. But sometimes you need to adjust the textures and albedos, click on each Material and fix the textures and albedos to improve the finish

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOeodlLTx8g

Comment: The textures are not embedded... I'll say this again... I gave you a link to the exact model, and I even told you that I have textures folder separately. I have tried your steps beforehand, the textures button is not enabled.

Comment: If the textures are not embedded then you need to create the materials individually, right click on the project folder where you want to create all the materials and in the menu click create > material, then you need to assign all the textures to each material, finally drag the material to the part of the model you want to texturize

Comment: Well, that is what I did, but I wanted to get an automatic solution

Comment: did you find an automatic solution to tihs tedious issue?

Comment: I haven't found an automatic solution to this issue, i  still need to do it manually :(